# Get class name from Class object

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a Class object, and besides finding the class name of an object, is it possible to get the class name from the Class object?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you just need the class name, consider using [flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getQualifiedClassName%28%29). describeType operations can be slow so if you don't need the other data it will be faster.

Comment: capital 'N': ``flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName``

Answer (score 4):

The describeType() function will help you. By passing the class to it, it will return XML detailing all you need to know about the class including its name.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#describeType()